# Flutter Stripe Bancontact provide return_url

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, payment, checkout

Hello guys I wanted to add Bancontact as a payment method to a flutter app but I got this error.

flutter: StripeException(error: LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: There was an unexpected error -- try again in a few seconds, message: You must provide a `return_url` when confirming a PaymentIntent with the payment method type bancontact., stripeErrorCode: , declineCode: null, type: invalid_request_error))

I dont know where I should add the return_url since confirmPayment dont take return_url.

here's my code:

```
Future stripeBanContact({
  required String clientSecret,
}) async {
  Stripe.publishableKey = '**';
  await Stripe.instance.createPaymentMethod(
    params: const PaymentMethodParams.bancontact(
      paymentMethodData: PaymentMethodData(
        billingDetails: BillingDetails(
          name: "**",
          email: "**",
          phone: "**",
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  await Stripe.instance.confirmPayment(
    paymentIntentClientSecret: clientSecret,
  );
}
```

I expect to fix this error and any advice about how to make the function functional will be great since im a bit lost.

Comment: They have an example code snippet on their documentation, https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_payment. I think you'd want the following:

await Stripe.instance.confirmPayment(
    paymentIntentClientSecret: clientSecret,
    confirmParams: {
       return_url: 'https://example.com',
    },
  ); Moving this comment here instead